# Basis of a topology different from the standard topology in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: general-topology

I'm trying to prove the following statement:

> For every $x\in \mathbb{R}$ and every $\epsilon>0$, define $V(x,\epsilon)=\lbrace x\rbrace \cup\lbrace q\in \mathbb{Q}: |x-q|<\epsilon \rbrace$ and let $B=\lbrace V(x,\epsilon):x\in \mathbb{R}, \epsilon>0\rbrace$. The set $B$ forms a basis for a topology $\tau$ on $\mathbb{R}$. Prove that $\tau$ is strictly finer than the standard topology $\tau_{S}$ on $\mathbb{R}$.

Here is what I have tried so far: let $y\in\mathbb{R}$ be arbitrary with $y\in B(x,\epsilon)$ (basis element for the standard topology). Then this implies that $|x-y|<\epsilon$ which implies that $-\epsilon <x-y<\epsilon$.

I have the suspicion, however, that I have to use the denseness in $\mathbb{Q}$ somewhere in order to show that there is a basis element $V(x,\epsilon)$ for the topology $\tau$ such that $y\in V(x,\epsilon)\subset B(x,\epsilon)$ and this will hence prove that $\tau$ is finer than the standard topology $\tau_{S}$ on $\mathbb{R}$, but I don't have any idea how to proceed further. Any advice, hints, or any sort of help would be appreciated by me.

Comment: There exists some $\epsilon'$ such that $y \in B(y, \epsilon') \subseteq B(x, \epsilon)$. Then $y \in V(y, \epsilon') \subseteq B(y, \epsilon') \subseteq B(x, \epsilon)$.

Comment: But how can I show that in a more rigorous way? Do I have to use Denseness in $\mathbb{Q}$ in such case?

Comment: It take some work to show $B$ is a basis, and not a sub-basis.  You have to show $V(x,r)\cap V(y,s)$ is the union of elements in $B.$ Not hard to prove.

Comment: Denseness of $\Bbb Q$ plays no role. $V(x,r) \subseteq B(x,r)$ is all you need, and this is  obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $(a,b)$ be a standard open interval. For each $x\in (a,b)$ define $\epsilon(x)=\min(b-x,x-a).$

Then $$x\in V(x,\epsilon(x))\subseteq (a,b).\tag 1$$

So let $$U=\bigcup_{x\in(a,b)} V(x,\epsilon(x))$$

Then, by the first half of (1), $(a,b)\subseteq U.$

By the second half of (1), $U\subseteq (a,b).$

That means that $U=(a,b).$

This means any open set in the standard topology is open in your new topology.

But $V(x,\epsilon)$ is never open in the standard topology.

So the new topology has all the old open sets, and some new ones.

---

You don’t really need the rationals to be dense. Another set which isn’t dense gives a similar topology, but where it isn’t dense, the topology is just the discret topology.

So, if you replace $\mathbb Q$ with $\mathbb Z,$ you just get the discrete topology on $\mathbb R.$

Answer (score 1):

If $U$ is open in $\tau_S$ and $x \in U$ then we know that there is some ball $B(x,r)$  such that $x \in B(x,r) \subseteq U$. It's clear that $V(x,r) \subseteq B(x,r)$, so $x$ is also an interior point of $U$ wrt $\tau$.

So $U$ is also $\tau$-open and $\tau_S \subseteq \tau$ is clear.

$V(x,r)$ is always countable so not open in $\tau_S$. So the inclusion is strict.

---

Note that $\Bbb P$ is a closed and discrete subspace of $(\Bbb R, \tau)$ so that it is not Lindelöf or second countable, but it *is* easily seen to be separable and first-countable. So $(\Bbb R, \tau)$ is non-metrisable. It is also not normal by Jones' lemma, but *is* completely regular and zero-dimensonal.